# queryDSL returns one record if limit and offset provided

Tags: java, jpa, querydsl

I am using queryDSL JPA.

I am trying to load data in chunks, so I am using `.offset()` and `.limit()`
I am querying 'single_entry' table, that contains 10000 records.

I use  the following function to query data

```
private Collection<SingleEntry> getSingleEntries(FiscalPeriod fp, Predicate filter, Integer offset, Integer limit) {
    BooleanExpression initialFilter = getSingleEntriesFilter(fp);
    return query.selectFrom(QSingleEntry.singleEntry).where(initialFilter.and(filter)).offset(offset).limit(limit).fetch();
}

private BooleanExpression getSingleEntriesFilter(FiscalPeriod fp) {
    int period = fp.getPeriod();
    int year = fp.getYear();
    QSingleEntryModification sem = QSingleEntryModification.singleEntryModification;
    QSingleEntry se = QSingleEntry.singleEntry;

    BooleanExpression fiscalPeriodMatches = se.year.eq(year).and(se.period.loe(period));
    //excludes single entries that moved from this period
    BooleanExpression excludeMoved = se.documentNumber.notIn(query.selectDistinct(sem.documentNumber).from(sem)
            .where(sem.moved.eq(true)
                    .and(sem.originYear.eq(year)
                            .and(sem.originPeriod.loe(period)).and(sem.movedToPeriod.gt(period).or(sem.movedToYear.ne(year))))));
    BooleanExpression movedToPeriodOrNonMoved = se.documentNumber.in(query.selectDistinct(sem.documentNumber).from(sem)
            .where(sem.moved.eq(false).and(sem.originYear.eq(year).and(sem.originPeriod.loe(period))).or(sem.movedToPeriod.loe(period).and(sem.movedToYear.eq(year)))));
    return fiscalPeriodMatches.and(excludeMoved).or(movedToPeriodOrNonMoved);
}
```

Hibernate produces the following query when offset equals 0 and limit are set:

```
select
   * //replaced with * to be concise
from
    single_entry singleentr0_ 
where
    (
        singleentr0_.year=? 
        and singleentr0_.period<=? 
        and (
            singleentr0_.document_number not in  (
                select
                    distinct TOP(?) singleentr1_.document_number 
                from
                    single_entry_modification singleentr1_ 
                where
                    singleentr1_.moved=? 
                    and singleentr1_.origin_year=? 
                    and singleentr1_.origin_period<=? 
                    and (
                        singleentr1_.moved_to_period>? 
                        or singleentr1_.moved_to_year<>?
                    )
            )
        ) 
        or singleentr0_.document_number in (
            select
                distinct singleentr2_.document_number 
            from
                single_entry_modification singleentr2_ 
            where
                singleentr2_.moved=? 
                and singleentr2_.origin_year=? 
                and singleentr2_.origin_period<=? 
                or singleentr2_.moved_to_period<=? 
                and singleentr2_.moved_to_year=?
        )
    ) 
    and singleentr0_.account_number=?
```

This query return one result, however, if I run this query in a database manager, it returns a correct number of results.

If the offset is non-zero and the limit is set Hibernate generates following query:

```
WITH query AS (SELECT
    inner_query.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
ORDER BY
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as __hibernate_row_nr__ 
FROM
    ( select
        * //replaced with * to be concise
    from
        single_entry singleentr0_ 
    where
        (singleentr0_.year=? 
        and singleentr0_.period<=? 
        and (singleentr0_.document_number not in  (select
            distinct singleentr1_.document_number 
        from
            single_entry_modification singleentr1_ 
        where
            singleentr1_.moved=? 
            and singleentr1_.origin_year=? 
            and singleentr1_.origin_period<=? 
            and (singleentr1_.moved_to_period>? 
            or singleentr1_.moved_to_year<>?))) 
        or singleentr0_.document_number in (select
            distinct singleentr2_.document_number 
        from
            single_entry_modification singleentr2_ 
        where
            singleentr2_.moved=? 
            and singleentr2_.origin_year=? 
            and singleentr2_.origin_period<=? 
            or singleentr2_.moved_to_period<=? 
            and singleentr2_.moved_to_year=?)) 
        and singleentr0_.account_number=? ) inner_query ) SELECT
            * //replaced with * to be concise
        FROM
            query 
        WHERE
            __hibernate_row_nr__ >= ? 
            AND __hibernate_row_nr__ < ?
```

that query returns the correct number of results.

I have 2 questions:
1. why the first query returns only 1 result?
2. why in the first query TOP(?) appears not in top level select but in subquery?

Please let me know if additional source code should be provided
Thank you!